# Переписывание таблиц Excel с помощью xlrd и xlwt

Tags: python, массивы

Есть таблица, нужно скопировать значение двух столбцов и записать их в другую таблицу.

Сделал так:

```
import xlrd
import xlwt

import numpy as np
file_location = "C:/Users/blm/Desktop/Cu4Cycle1.xls"
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
first_col = sheet.col_values(0)
second_col = sheet.col_values(1)
lst = [sheet.col_values(0)]
nst = [sheet.col_values(1)]  
wb = xlwt.Workbook()
ws = wb.add_sheet('A Test Sheet')

for i in range(0, len(nst[0])):
  ws.write(0, i, lst[0][i])
wb.save('grape.xls')
```

Выдает ошибку:

> ValueError: column index (256) not an int in range(256)

Как исправить?

Comment: Начните с форматирования кода в вопросе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python использует табуляцию для выделения блоков, поэтому это

```
for i in range (len(lst[0])
ws.write(0, i, lst[0][i])
```

надо заменить на это

```
for i in range (len(lst[0]): 
    ws.write(0, i, lst[0][i])
```

Comment: Да, уже заметил эту ошибку. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

[Pandas модуль](http://pbpython.com/excel-pandas-comp.html) позволяет сделать это гораздо более лаконичным образом:

```
import pandas as pd

file_location = "C:/Users/blm/Desktop/Cu4Cycle1.xls"
# читаем столбцы `A:B` и записываем их в новый excel file
pd.read_excel(file_location, parse_cols='A:B') \
  .to_excel('grape.xls', sheet_name='A Test Sheet', index=False)
```